# How to exclude internal jar from aar Xamarin library binding?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, dji-sdk, xamarin-binding

I have an `aar` library binding which includes corrupted `jar` - probably obfuscated. `aar` itself needs this `jar` but I don't need binding for them. The issue is when I build App which using this binding I am getting an error that: `ERROR: unable to open 'obj\Release\81\lp\0\jl\assets\sdkclasses.jar' as a zip file: -40 "sdkclasses.jar' as a zip file: -40"`. Can I somehow skip (exclude) `jar`s from within 'aar'?

Example repo: https://github.com/pkalwig/DjiSdkBindingSample

Comment: Xamarin does not directly support asset-based jars in its build process, I bound a slew of the DJI SDKs and this was the worst part (I ended up mod'ing the actual Xamarin build process). To be honest, the runtime limitations (performance mainly) occurred using Xamarin in this case is not worth it for a drone app, you can learn Kotlin faster than trying to work around all the issues 

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read the [Troubleshooting Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/) guide by Xamarin

Where they have shown in detail how to handle and troubleshoot issues that occur during and after creating a binding.

I would suggest you check the below problems which seem to be relevant in your use case.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/#Possible_Causes

Comment: Then why this jar want to be unzipped?

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for pointing it out, learned something new today

Comment: Because Xamarin is "incorrectly" handling it. This is not a directly supported "feature" in Android via Gradle/etc.. and is not a documented part of the normal Android build process, so thus a jar is normally not stored as an Asset and Xamarin does not know what to do with it. DJI is using it as a software security feature, i.e. it is a hack

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for all the pointers, By the way shouldn't we just close this as too broad?